# Tensorflow BiRNN dynamic dimension size for input data

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, recurrent-neural-network

I have issue with constructing Input data for BiRNN network.

I'm create License Plate detection system like described : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.05610v1.pdf

I have got to "4.2.3 Sequence Labelling" part where I need to train BiRNN with dataset of (total_count_of_images, None, 256) shape, None because it's length of image and and it is different for every picture in data set.

Let's say I have 3000 Images. Then shape would look like :

train.shape : (3000,) but really it is (3000, None, 256) !?

So I got example code from

https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/bidirectional_rnn.ipynb

So I'm struggling even with starting to train my RNN. I don't understand how I need to constrct input data/model, input placeholders, variables etc to achieve any training process.

As far as I know everything should work. My code :

```
reset_graph()

'''

Dataset : (10000, 784)
Labels : (10000, 10)

To classify images using a bidirectional reccurent neural network, we consider
every image row as a sequence of pixels. Because MNIST image shape is 28*28px,
we will then handle 28 sequences of 28 steps for every sample.
'''

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_iters = 100 # 100000
display_step = 10
batch_size = 40

# Network Parameters
n_input = 256 # data inpit size/256D
n_steps = 256 # timesteps
n_hidden = 200 # hidden layer num of features
n_classes = 36 # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits and a-z letters)

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [batch_size, None , n_input], name='input_placeholder')
y = tf.placeholder("float", [batch_size, None, n_classes], name='labels_placeholder')

# Define weights
weights = {
    # Hidden layer weights => 2*n_hidden because of foward + backward cells
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2*n_hidden, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

def BiRNN(x, weights, biases):

    print('Input x',x.get_shape().as_list())
    print('weights[\'out\']', weights['out'].get_shape().as_list())
    print('biases[\'out\']', biases['out'].get_shape().as_list())

    # Prepare data shape to match `bidirectional_rnn` function requirements
    # Current data input shape: (batch_size, n_steps, n_input)
    # Required shape: 'n_steps' tensors list of shape (batch_size, n_input)

    # Permuting batch_size and n_steps
    #x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
    #print('Transposed x',x.get_shape().as_list())
    # Reshape to (n_steps*batch_size, n_input)
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, n_steps])
    print('Reshaped x',x.get_shape().as_list())

    # Split to get a list of 'n_steps' tensors of shape (batch_size, n_input)
    x = tf.split(0, n_input, x)
    print(len(x),'of [ ',x[0],' ] kinds')

    # Define lstm cells with tensorflow
    # Forward direction cell
    lstm_fw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
    # Backward direction cell
    lstm_bw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)

    # Get lstm cell output
    outputs, _, _ = rnn.bidirectional_rnn(lstm_fw_cell, lstm_bw_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
    print( len(outputs),'of [ ',outputs[0],' ] kinds' )

    # Linear activation, using rnn inner loop last output
    ret = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']
    print('ret', ret.get_shape().as_list())

    return ret

pred = BiRNN(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Evaluate model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
```

OUTPUT :

```
Input x [40, None, 256]
weights['out'] [400, 36]
biases['out'] [36]
Reshaped x [None, 256]
256 of [  Tensor("split:0", shape=(?, 256), dtype=float32)  ] kinds
256 of [  Tensor("concat:0", shape=(?, 400), dtype=float32)  ] kinds
ret [None, 36]
```

Everything just right there.
Problems start at session part :

```
# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    step = 1

    batch_data = batch_gen(batch_size)

    # Keep training until reach max iterations
    while step * batch_size  < training_iters:
        batch_x, batch_y = next(batch_data)
        print(batch_x.shape)
        print(batch_y.shape)
        #m[:,0, None, None].shape
        #Run optimization op (backprop)
        print('Optimizer')
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

        if step % display_step == 0:
            print('Display')
            # Calculate batch accuracy
            acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            # Calculate batch loss
            loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            print("Iter " + str(step * batch_size) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                  "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                  "{:.5f}".format(acc))
        step += 1
    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Calculate accuracy for 128 mnist test images
    test_len = 128
    test_data = mnist.test.images[:test_len].reshape((-1, n_steps, n_input))
    test_label = mnist.test.labels[:test_len]
    print("Testing Accuracy:", \
        sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_data, y: test_label}))
```

There I got following error :

```
(40,)
(40,)
Optimizer

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-96-a53814db8181> in <module>()
     14         #Run optimization op (backprop)
     15         print('Optimizer')
---> 16         sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
     17 
     18         if step % display_step == 0:

/home/nauris/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    715     try:
    716       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 717                          run_metadata_ptr)
    718       if run_metadata:
    719         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/home/nauris/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    886                 ' to a larger type (e.g. int64).')
    887 
--> 888           np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
    889 
    890           if not subfeed_t.get_shape().is_compatible_with(np_val.shape):

/home/nauris/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    480 
    481     """
--> 482     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    483 
    484 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks everyone in advance.

Realized that error occurs because you cannot feed numpy ndarray with inconsistent dimensions such as (3000, None, 256) in my case. Haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: Issue resolved. Needed to use Sparse Tensors and different data structures.